# HTML/CSS How to connect a list to h tag and word-spacing

Tags: html, css

my task is to create a  tag which CONTAINS an ordered list, that's my idea:

```html
<section>
<h2>Ich kann physische Auszeichnungen:</h2> 
<ol>
  <li><b>Coffee, Bold Text </b></li>
  <li><i>Tea, Italic Text</i></li>
  <li><u>Milk, Underlined Text</u></li>
</ol>
</section>
```

is this correct? Second problem:

I am asked to make the `<h>` tag size 300% and word-spacing between listed text 50px with CSS styling, that's what I do:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 300%; 
}
ol { 
    word-spacing: 50px;
}
```

it seems to be working, but when I do that, the order (1.2.3) of the list disappears, how should I fix it?

Comment: With regards to your first question: it is mostly correct. b, i and u should not be used unless you can think of a compelling reason to use them. (Paraphrasing the official rules here.) Otherwise, styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong element for word spacing.

Try this:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 300%; 
}
b, i, u { 
    word-spacing: 50px;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLjy6xgp/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. You can wrap a `<p>` tag around your elements inside the `li` - then add the word spacing to the `p` tag

```
h2 {font-size: 300%;}

ol p { word-spacing: 50px; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5kz8p5/

Comment: That adds more white space between the lines.

Comment: He specifically said `word spacing` if he isn't correctly naming his properties then it will be hard to solve his problem. If he is referring to `margin` or `line-height` then he needs to use proper termonology @AdamBuchananSmith

Comment: I am sorry, I miss spoke, I meant line height. It adds vertical white space between the list elements due to the line height of the `<p>` tag. and is not inline with what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 300%; 
}
li { 
    word-spacing: 50px;
    margin-left:30px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/ntwgpbd7/)

Seems that the wordspacing is messing with the numbering. Adding a bit of left margin works.